# Is $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ x $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ x $\mathbb{F}_2[X]\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{F}_2$ multilinear?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

> $t$ : $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ x $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ x $\mathbb{F}_2[X]\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{F}_2$
>
> $t(f,g,h):=f(0)g(0)h(1)+f(0)g(1)h(0)+f(1)g(0)h(0)$

How can I know if this is multilinear? Do I have to take random polynomials with $f,g$ and $h$?

I know that I can take such a basis {0,1},{1,0} for $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, but I don't know how to implicate it in $t$.

Comment: Do you have a definition of _multilinear_? Maybe try to verify that

Comment: You don't need to talk about bases to check linearity. Linearity is more fundamental than a choice of coordinates. Just look at the definition of (multi)linearity and see that there is no mention of such things. Once you have a basis, linear maps get a matrix representation (at least if the spaces are finite), sure. But that's something else.

Comment: @Federico https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map this is the general definition, but my problem is using $t$, can I assume random functions $f,g,h$?

Comment: What do you mean by _"can I assume random functions $f,g,h$?"_?

Comment: You have to verify for instance that $t(f_1+f_2,g,h)=t(f_1,g,h)+t(f_2,g,h)$ etc...

Comment: @Dada If $t$ is to be multilinear, the requirements must be upheld for _any_ $f,g,h$. So yes, assume they are arbitrary (which is different from random). Also note that you probably need more than three functions at a time, so it may be a good idea to use indices. On the other hand, if you want to _disprove_ multilinearity, then a single choice of counterexample is enough.

Comment: @Federico for example: let $f=X^4+1$, $g=X$, $h=X^3+X^2+1$, and then trying for the definition of $t$

Comment: Multilinearity must hold for **all** functions, not just a couple of them that you select. Try proving the equality I wrote before. If you see that it fails, maybe you can come up with a counterexample instead

Comment: In that case, $t(f,g,h)=1$. And that's all you can say from that.